# Как взаимодействовать с объектами на странице из расширения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension, extension

Пишу простое расширение, в котором есть только 1 поле `input type='text'`

**Что оно должно делать:** 
В поле вставляется цифровое значение, порядка 13 знаков(к примеру: `1347258117916`)которое обрезается. После чего необходимо на открытой вкладке просто чекнуть соответствующий `checkbox`
Поиск в сети окончательно меня запутал с решением этого вопроса.

В **manifest.json** у меня вот что:

```
{
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "matches": ["*://url", "https://url"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": [ "jquery.js", "background.js" ],
        "css": [ "style.css" ]
   }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ 
        "jquery.js" 
    ],
   "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "main.html",
        "matches": ["*://url", "https://url"],
        "default_icon": "App.png",
        "default_title": "Exten$ion"
   },
   "icons": {
      "128": "App.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Самый Обычный main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="ti_num" type="text" style="width:350px;height:15px;" value="">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

код из **Popup.js**, который подключается в main.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ti_num').each(function () {//функция очистки
    $(this).data('defvalue', this.value);
});

$('#ti_num').on('input', function(){
        str = $('#ti_num').val();
        res = str.substring(4,11);
        propt = 'table_checkbox_'+res;
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({propt});
        console.log(propt);
        /* Очистка Input, для вставки следующего значения
    $('#ti_num').each(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).data('defvalue'));
        });*/
    });
});
```

код в **background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(propt){
    console.log(propt);
    $('input:checkbox[name='+propt+']').attr('checked',true);
});
```

В таком виде выполняется тольк обработка вставленного числа, чекбокс не чекается и консоль чистая, без какой-либо ошибки.
Совсем запутался, как правильно передать переменную propt из окна расширения в background.js, чтобы нужный чекбокс чекнуть?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы передать пелеменную propt, в bg.js - *нужно всего лишь каждое утро... (код белоу)*

```js
// любой файл.js расширения:
let propt = 'text';
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'propt', value: propt});

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((r, sender, sR)=>{
    console.log(r.message, r.value);
    if(r.message === 'propt'){
        // код
        sR(true);
    }
});
```

Как отправить, с любого скрипта расширения, пелеменную - в активную вкладку:

```js
// любой файл.js расширения (popup.js):
let propt = 'text';
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, ([tab])=>{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tab.id, {message: 'heyActiveTab', value: propt});
});

// content_scripts.js на активной вкладке
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((r, sender, sR)=>{
    console.log(r.message, r.value);
    if(r.message === 'heyActiveTab'){
        // code here
        alert(r.value);
        sR(true);
    }
});
```

Некоторые "замечания" и чтиво:

1. [прочитать](https://learn.javascript.ru/structure) и [это](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/struktura-html-koda) (структура)
2. [прочитать](https://learn.javascript.ru/variables), про пелеменные (научись их создавать)
3. по экстету [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) да и вообще [гайд](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)
4. [это читать](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/), если есть 18+ уже, вернее es6
5. также про папки не забывай, почему структура файлов - *елена полено*
6. await реди локального файла.. 1 строка попаута, как по мне - не нужна
7. функция очистки `$('#ti_num').val('');`, btw jq селектор по иду отдает 1 элемент всегда, ич бесполезен

Comment: Данная реализация нужна для решения рабочего так сказать процесса. Знакомство с js поверхностное.
Ссылки ваши обязательно почитаю для общего сведения.
Очистка была такая, потому что где-то тут была тема, что писать .val("") - не эстетично. Потому взял что было предложено.

Comment: Вижу все таки примеры накидал. ок.
1. Эти все ссылки полезны ток разработчику. Структура приведеная очищена спеиально для темы и ваши претензии имхо - бред.
2. переменные объявляются и спокойно живут и без let. Не видел чтобы вообще кто-то так писал. Типа с умничал???
3. справка chrome у меня итак открыта.
4. бесполезная ссылка для меня
5. зачем мне твои папки? Имхо бред это делать, мне важен результат. и расширение только для меня.
6. Убрал 1 строку, вы правы без нее все работает.
7. ответ выше.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в отправке. Помог пример из справки.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: 'messages', value: propt});
});
```

Comment: Не нужно дублировать ответ. Лучше отметьте [существующий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1107945/15479) как принятый.